# Is it possible to use a single SharePoint public url associated with different SharePoint web applications?

Tags: sharepoint-server, url, web-application, setup

We are currently setting up our SharePoint Sites, and we are thinking if we could use a single public url to associate it with different web application. Please see diagram below:

[image]

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can achieve this. As every web application create a unique Site in IIS.

What i am thinking, you can create multiple site collections in your web application instead of one web app for it, hr, ce.